# Возможно ли написание чат-бота для Telegram на php без использования библиотек?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Ситуация такова - первый раз пишу бота для Telegram  и столкнулся с рядом проблем. Во-первых, нет виртуального выделенного сервера для работы с Composer, следовательно, такие библиотеки, как Telegram Bot SDK реализовать не получится. 
Начал писать без библиотек и столкнулся с тем, что в интернете слишком мало информации о том, как это сделать. Не могли бы вы подсказать, где возможно найти ответы, на такие вопросы, как: реализация инлайн клавиатуры, кнопок, передача данных по нажатию на кнопки и т.д.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: А как вы хотите работать с телеграмом без сервера ? Если вы используете bot API то работать без сервера не выйдет.

Comment: В том и дело, что я не собираюсь использовать библиотеки, если такой путь вообще возможен. 
Пока что бот работает с хоста через webhook, но документацию нашёл лишь о том, как реализовать простые текстовые ответы, когда как нужны полные ответы с картинками, ссылками, кнопками и т.д.